# ExpressJs dynamic routing not working properly with react get request

Tags: reactjs, express, request, endpoint, dynamic-routing

I have a simple api and client application. Api written with express js and client-side is react.
I arranged the react dynamic routing but when I try to send get request to endpoint with dynamic path, I cannot get the dynamic path and dynamic path parameter. It is like no request coming from client to api. What is the reason of this ?

Note: I can get data from api and I can post data to api. The problem occurs only with dynamic routing. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was sending request to `http://localhost:3000/products/:name` but that makes no sense because there is no such endpoint. I changed request path as `http://localhost:3000/products/${name}`. Then the problem solved. I can send request to dynamic endpoint like '.../${name}' not '.../:name'.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use :slug for the router
example: /auth/v1/products/:name

Comment: I just overlooked a tiny, little detail. It is about path but not at api. But thank for your answer.